# Реализация админки

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Добрый день!
Расскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом реализовать админку на Ruby on Rails?
Если на PHP-фреймворках это обычно новое приложение, то как дела с этим обстоят здесь?
Спасибо!

Comment: В общем и целом ничем не отличается от написания основной части сайта.

Comment: это я понимаю, но как собственно организовать саму админку? Создать еще одно приложение и поместить его в другую папку? Не ясен именно этот момент

Comment: @Vyacheslav_Alexeev, зачем так сложно, почему просто не создать admin_controller и не напихать в него нужных action'ов?, почтиайте про [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, отдельное приложение создавать не нужно. Можно админку вынести в engine если планируете её подключать и использовать на нескольких сайтах. Ну вот как-то так:

Контроллеры:
app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "secret"

  layout "admin/application"
end
```

app/controllers/admin/movies_controller.rb

```
class Admin::MoviesController < Admin::ApplicationController
  # crud
end
```

Роуты:

```
# admin area
get "/admin" => "admin/movies#index"
namespace :admin do
  resources :movies
end
```

Вьюшки:

- app/views/admin/movies/
- app/views/admin/layouts/application.html.erb

Answer (score 2):

Для этого можно использовать специальный [гем](http://activeadmin.info/)

Answer (score 1):

Про engine вам уже ответили.

Из готовых решений мне больше всего нравится АктивАдмин. Также очень популярен Рейлс-админ.

Примерный список можно посмотреть: [Здесь](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces)